# Serial Port Mode C#

Tags: c#, command-line, serial-port

I am trying to configure a serial port on C# to send binary files to my port. Normally, I would write in my Windows terminal:

```
    mode COM3 19200, n, 8, 1, p
```

Then, to send my file, I would write:

```
    copy /b myFile.plt COM3
```

How can I perform these instructions on C#?

Thanks :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            Byte[] data =  File.ReadAllBytes("myFile.plt");

            port.Write(data, 0, data.Count());

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: The port has to be opened before you can write on it. I would simply add `port.Open();` after it is created.